# ng-click to undo event AngularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

The idea is to create a checklist. When the user clicks on a circle it changes its background color. If he clicks it again it should reset the color.

[image]

I managed to change the background to green when the user checks his progress like this:

```
<i class="circle1" 
   ng-style="myStyle1" 
   ng-click="myStyle1={'background-color':'green'}">1</i>
```

Now my problem is how to reset the color to white when the user clicks again?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to introduce a css class which is toggled when you click the element. You can do this with a combination of `ng-class` and using `ng-click` to toggle a variable.

```
<i class="circle1" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled === true}" ng-click="isToggled = !isToggled">1 - {{isToggled}}</i>
```

```js
angular.module("app", []);
```

```css
.circle1 {
  background: red;
}

.green-circle {
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <i class="circle1" ng-class="{'green-circle': isToggled === true}" ng-click="isToggled = !isToggled">1 - {{isToggled}}</i>
</div>
```

The downfall of this solution is that you would need a different `isToggled` variable for each circle. A better and more re-usable solution would be to create a directive that handles this:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.circle1 {
  background: red;
}
.green-circle {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <i class="circle1" toggle-class="green-circle">One</i>
  <i class="circle1" toggle-class="green-circle">Two</i>
  <i class="circle1" toggle-class="green-circle">Three</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but it only works for one circle. I cannot seem to change the rest

Comment: You would need to use a different `isToggled` for each circle

Comment: @Hana I added a reusable solution that doesn't suffer from the previous problems

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you follow this algorithm and write some code,

1. write a common function to reset color
2. Call that function via ng-click and get currently clicked element
3. and reset color of that elements plus all elements next to it by changing it's class

**Remember** resetting color of all nodes next to current code is must, else it will not look like **Progress**. It will just look like on-off buttons

You can post code again if you are getting some errors

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <i class="circle1" id ="circle1" ng-click="changeColor()">1</i>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.changeColor= function() {
    var i=0
    if(i%2 ==0)
    {
    document.getElementbyID('circle1').style.background ="original color"
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementbyID('circle1').style.background ="green"
    }
  };
```